# How to derive type-2 maximum likelihood method for RVM regression

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, mathematical-statistics, derivative

According to PRML book(7.85,7.86,exercise 7.12), the marginal likelihood for RVM regression is
$$ \ln p(y|X,\alpha,\beta)=−1/2\{N\ln2π + \ln|C| + y^TC^{−1}y\} $$
$$ A=diag\{\alpha_1,..,\alpha_D\} $$
$$ C=\beta^{-1}I+\Phi A^{-1} \Phi^T $$
$$ \Phi=[\phi(x_1); \phi(x_2)...; \phi(x_N)]$$
or equivalently(MLaPP book exercise 13.3):
$$ \ln p(y|X,\alpha,\beta)= \frac 1 2\ln \beta - \frac \beta 2 ||y-Xm||_2^2+\frac 1 2 \sum_j\ln\alpha_j-\frac 1 2m^TAm+\frac 1 2\ln|\Sigma|-\frac D 2\ln2\pi$$
$$ m=\beta\Sigma\Phi^Ty $$
$$ \Sigma=\beta\Phi^T\Phi+A $$
to maximize the marginal likelihood, we take derivatives of it with respect to $\alpha_i$ and setting these to zero.

But, I can't derive the iterative update formula (7.87) in PRML book:
$$ \alpha_i^{new}=\frac {1-\alpha_i\Sigma_{ii}} {m_i^2} $$
The book (and [Tipping's RVM paper](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume1/tipping01a/tipping01a.pdf)) seems to treat vector $ m $ as constant when compute $ \frac {\partial \ln p(y|X,\alpha,\beta)} {\partial \alpha_i} $, while treat $ \Sigma $ as function of $ \alpha_i $, but I think both of them are dependent on $ \alpha_i $.

Did I misunderstanding something here?

Answer (score 1):

You are right in saying that *m* depends on α<sub>i</sub>.

The authors are eluding a subtelty there. It is the same one they describe on p.318, where a<sub>N</sub>* is equivalent to *m* and θ to α<sub>i</sub> in this case.

The contribution of *m* to the gradient of the marginal likelihood w.r.t α<sub>i</sub> is zero. *m* is the mean (and thus mode) of the posterior distribution for the weights, so its gradient with respect to *m* vanishes, and its gradient w.r.t α<sub>i</sub> is the dot product of that zero gradient with the gradient of *m* w.r.t α<sub>i</sub>.

The same trick is also used for equation 3.89 and 7.115.